How to disable transparency for view attached to window as TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
After migrating from Android 9 to Android 13 the view attached to WindowManager with FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE flag, became semitransparent.
How to disable semi transparency for this view?
val windowManager: WindowManager = ...
val view: View = ...

val layoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            PixelFormat.RGBA_8888,
        )

windowManager.addView(
            view,
            layoutParams,
        )


